# pass Json to a custom AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to pass argument to a custom directive

My **directive** is :

```
phonecatApp.directive('demoDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
      template: '<div></div>',
      replace: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var el = angular.element('<span/>');

        console.log(JSON.stringify(attrs)); // Here I want to print json passed as arguments

        var day = ["zondag","maandag" ,"dinsdag", "woensdag" ,"donderdag" , "vrijdag" , "zaterdag"];
            var d = new Date();
            var n = d.getDay(); 
            var temp = "";


        for(i=n ; i<6 ; i++){



             var myString = '<li> <input class="checkleveringsdag" name="leveringsdag" value="2014-10-14" checked=""  type="radio">&nbsp;' + day[i] + '</li>';
             temp += myString;
            }
        for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++){

             var myString = '<li> <input class="checkleveringsdag" name="leveringsdag" value="2014-10-14" checked=""  type="radio">&nbsp;' + day[i] + '</li>';
             temp += myString;
            }
        $compile(temp)(scope);
        element.append(temp);
      }
    }
  });
```

My **HTML**:

```
<ul  class="leveringsdag" style="margin-top:20px;" demo-directive =  "{{data.name}}">


 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this with directive bindings, documented here. Look for the "scope" property of the directive definition.

https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/guide/directive

Answer (score 0):

```
 phonecatApp.directive('demoDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div></div>',
      replace: true,
      scope:
      {
         data: '='
      }
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var el = angular.element('<span/>');

        console.log(JSON.stringify(attrs)); // Here I want to print json passed as arguments

        var day = ["zondag","maandag" ,"dinsdag", "woensdag" ,"donderdag" , "vrijdag" , "zaterdag"];
            var d = new Date();
            var n = d.getDay(); 
            var temp = "";


        for(i=n ; i<6 ; i++){



             var myString = '<li> <input class="checkleveringsdag" name="leveringsdag" value="2014-10-14" checked=""  type="radio">&nbsp;' + day[i] + '</li>';
             temp += myString;
            }
        for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++){

             var myString = '<li> <input class="checkleveringsdag" name="leveringsdag" value="2014-10-14" checked=""  type="radio">&nbsp;' + day[i] + '</li>';
             temp += myString;
            }
        $compile(temp)(scope);
        element.append(temp);
      }
    }
  });
```

Try this:

```
<demo-directive data="data"></demo-directive>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/niezbor/dd4s579y/)

Comment: not working  error :

ERROR: Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$parse/syntax?p0=data&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=3&p3=%7B%7Bdata%7D%7D&p4=data%7D%7D
throwError@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js:169:297

Comment: Improved! Instead, `data={{data}}` should be the `data="data"`. I also added JsFiddle.